# javascript compare a number to object keys and get the value of the smallest

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Say we have:

```
const list = {
  1: "a",
  10: "b",
  20: "c",
  30: "d",
  40: "e"
};

const value = 15;
```

how can I efficiently compare the value against the object keys and get the value of the corresponding smaller range? and in this example, the expected answer is `b` because 15 is between 10 and 20.

i wanted to go this way:

```
for(var i=0; i < keys.length; i++){
    const item = parseInt(keys[i],10);
    if (item == keys[i]) {
      return keys[i];
    }
  }
```

but it is not efficient...

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems stopped you from finishing the task on your own?

Comment: An object literal is really not the correct structure for this, an array would make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` which will get all object keys in new array, and in `.some`(as suggested @Keith) stop the loop `(return true)`, when current value is getting bigger then `value`, your result will be stored in  `previous` var

```js
const list = {
  1: "a",
  10: "b",
  20: "c",
  30: "d",
  40: "e"
};

const value = 15;
let previous = 0;

Object.keys(list).some(k => {
  if (k > value) {
    return true;
  } 
  previous = k
});

console.log(list[previous]);
```

Comment: You might want to look in `Array.some`  this would work the same as your forEach but could short circuit the loop for you..

Comment: If you use some instead of forEach, and instead of `return` you do `return true`, it's going to work exactly as your `forEach` does, but will short circuit the loop.  IOW: it's not going to check `30 & 40`

Comment: It just skips the step `previous = k` but will proceed till the end of the array.

Comment: @Keith yeah I got what you mean, I have updated answer as you suggested

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the 1st index which is higher than the value. If none is found (return value is -1) take the element at the last key, else take the value at `keys[index - 1`. If the value is less than the 1st key it will return `undefined`.

```js
const findLowerClosest = (value, arr) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(list);
  const index = keys.findIndex(key => +key > value);
  const atKey = index !== -1 ? index - 1 : keys.length - 1;
  return arr[keys[atKey]];
}

const list = { 1: "a", 10: "b", 20: "c", 30: "d", 40: "e" };

console.log(findLowerClosest(15, list)); // b
console.log(findLowerClosest(75, list)); // e
console.log(findLowerClosest(-3, list)); // undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

If the keys are pre-sorted as in your example, use a binary search in log(n) time complexity. The catch is that dumping the keys into an array is a one-time linear step (and a one-time sort would be O(n log n) if necessary), so this is worth considering if you're planning on running multiple searches on one structure.

```js
const bisect = (a, target, lo=0, hi=a.length-1) => {
  while (lo <= hi) {
    const mid = ~~((hi - lo) / 2 + lo);

    if (a[mid] === target) {
      return a[mid];
    }
    else if (a[mid] < target) {
      lo = mid + 1;
    }
    else {
      hi = mid - 1;
    }
  }
  
  return a[~~((hi-lo)/2+lo)];
};

const list = {
  1: "a",
  10: "b",
  20: "c",
  30: "d",
  40: "e"
};

const keys = Object.keys(list);
console.log(list[bisect(keys, 15)]);
console.log(list[bisect(keys, 16)]);
console.log(list[bisect(keys, -50)]);
console.log(list[bisect(keys, 50)]);
```

Comment: This is cool, but `Object.keys` and `map` will result into linear complexity anyway.

Comment: Sure, but that's a one-time cost. If you're planning on running the routine more than one, that's amortized across the calls and wouldn't affect the time complexity, so choosing the appropriate algorithm is context-dependent.

Comment: Depends on how OP want't to use it. If he needs to search in the same object multiple times then yes, it's O(N logN).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to get the values which are less than 15, then do `Math.max`, then use this as key to retrieve value from the object

```js
const list = {
  1: "a",
  10: "b",
  20: "c",
  30: "d",
  40: "e"
};

const value = 15;

function getVal(n) {
  let getKeys = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(list).filter((item) => {
    return item < n
  }));
  return (list[getKeys])
}
console.log(getVal(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also `sort` the keys and then use `reduce` to find the lower key of the target range:

```js
const list = {
  1: "a",
  10: "b",
  20: "c",
  30: "d",
  40: "e"
};

const value = 15;
const answer = list[Object.keys(list)
                     .map(a => parseInt(a))
                     .sort((a, b) => a - b)
                     .reduce((acc, curr) => (acc < value && value < curr) ? acc : curr)];
                     
console.log(answer);
```